# How to test Spring Boot @Retryable in cucumber?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, integration-testing, wiremock-standalone

How do I write integration test for Spring Boot `@Retryable` in cucumber? I have a service method annotated with `@Retryable. MaxAttempt` is set to 3 and delay is 1. To mock the server, I am going to use wiremock.

I want to assert that the retry function is working correctly; meaning I want to write test scenario when the certain exception is thrown, the retry will be happened. and if it fails all the time then it will throw exception eventually else if it's successful during the retrials, then it should assert that the http status code is 200 OK.

I want to assert that retry is triggered for 3 times as its max attempt is set to 3 and http status code and maybe thrown exception? I've thought about some ideas to do this.. First one is to have `RetryableContext` class which have `int retryCount` varible. And each time retry is invoked then increase its value. --> honestly I don't think it's good idea.. Second one is to leverage spring AOP..? Not not really sure how to actually achieve it. I mean I am not confident with coding it out with this approach.

Comment: You should focus on the observable effects of the system. Not the internal workings. So in essence very the calls made to the mock server. https://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution yet?